# Open DataReader Error when using AsEnumerable

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, datareader

I am using the following function to Query an EF6 model using a bunch of query expressions that I have built programmatically:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Common application of generated queries to select the required resources
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The EF model type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The source of models (a DbSet)</param>
    /// <param name="queries">A collection of query pairs (database, local) to be applied as Where clauses</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static IEnumerable<string> ApplyCriteriaBase<T>(IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<(Expression, Expression)> queries) where T : DbResource
    {
        // Apply the database queries sequentially as Where clauses
        var resources = queries
            .Select(p => p.Item1)
            .Aggregate(source, (ds, qry) => ds.Where(qry as Expression<Func<T, bool>>))
            .Distinct();

        // If there are no local queries then don't bother fetching the whole object, just select the id in the generated SQL
        if(queries.All(q => q.Item2 == null))
            return resources
                .Select(a => a.Id.ToString());

        // Apply local queries
        // AsEnumerable() escapes from the IQueryable monad so the subsequent queries are executed locally on IEnumerable
        // This requires fetching the whole object because we dont know which bit is to be tested by the local query
        // Note that IEnumerable doesn't understand query expressions so we have to compile them to code and then invoke them
        return queries
            .Select(p => p.Item2)
            .Where(q => q != null)
            .Aggregate(
                resources.ToList() as IEnumerable<T>,  // .AsEnumerable() doesn't work
                (ds, qry) => ds.Where((qry as Expression<Func<T, bool>>).Compile().Invoke))
            .Select(a => a.Id.ToString());
    }
```

The idea is that queries contains 2-tuples of query expressions where the first of each is to be run against the database (MySql) and the second, if present, is to be run against the EF models returned.
It is my understanding that AsEnumerable() should permit the second query to be executed locally and lazily without pulling all of the results into memory.  Unfortunately this fails with the error:

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first."

The fix shown in the example, converting the result stream to a List, works correctly but is strict.
Why doesn't AsEnumerable() work and is there another way to process the results lazily?  Some instances of DbResource are very large and I only want to accumulate the Id of each resource.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: It sounds like the local filter is triggering lazy loading. Which in general is an issue with client filters and db providers not supporting MARS.

Comment: It is true that the local query will trigger lazy loading of data related to the models in resources.  Are you suggesting that these lazy loads are responsible for the error?

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, this would imply that there is no simple workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Because if the lazy loading is triggered during the enumeration of the main query result, the db reader is still open, and lazy loading is trying to open another. There is no problem with db providers which support MARS (like SqlServer), but is basically unavoidable problem with MySQL. The only workaround I can think of is to eager load the involved entities, or materialize the query as you did with `ToList`. The best of course is if possible, not use client filters involving navigation properties.